# Save ON OFF toggle switch status to data.txt file

Tags: php, html

Good morning, I need to save the state of some ON OFF switches in a file called data.txt.
The result will then be read by Arduino or ESP 32 and the like (but that's another story).

I'm a novice for the html JS and PHP language and the like and I have a lot of difficulty understanding its mechanisms.
I think it's easy for an expert, but honestly I don't know where to start.

The starting file should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS Toggle Switch with Sliding Button</title>
  <style>
    .toggle {
      --width: 80px;
      --height: calc(var(--width) / 3);

      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: var(--width);
      height: var(--height);
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .toggle input {
      display: none;
    }

    .toggle .labels {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .toggle .labels::after {
      content: attr(data-off);
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      color: #4d4d4d;
      background-color: #f19999;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    .toggle .labels::before {
      content: attr(data-on);
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      top: 0;
      left: calc(var(--width) * -1);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: green;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    .toggle input:checked~.labels::after {
      transform: translateX(var(--width));
    }

    .toggle input:checked~.labels::before {
      transform: translateX(var(--width));
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>prova</h1>
  <label class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="labels" data-on="ON" data-off="OFF"></span>
  </label>
  <br><br/>
  <label class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="labels" data-on="ON" data-off="OFF"></span>
  </label>
  <br><br/>
  <label class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="labels" data-on="ON" data-off="OFF"></span>
  </label>
</body>

</html>
```

It should then save the states in here, even better if it kept the previous settings for those that haven't been changed:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('data.txt', '');

$fp = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? "ON" : "OFF";

$data=$_POST['checkbox'];

$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');

fwrite($fp, $data);

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: have a look at [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) which might help on the frontend side of things.